# List all instances of the "Heading 1" style

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm trying to list every instance of the "Heading 1" style within my document (to eventually list them in a combobox on a form).

The following code appears to find the instances of "Heading 1", as there are the correct number of entries listed within the Immediate Window, but `.text` is returning nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim i as Integer

i = 1

With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    .Style = "Heading 1"

    Do
        blnFound = .Execute
        If blnFound Then
            Debug.Print i & " " & .Text
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the object you have has a .Text property. Selection has a .Text property. Try this:

```
Sub FindHeadings()
' October 28, 2014
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
' Set up the find conditions
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1

'Repeat while you find the style
blnFound = True
While blnFound
    With Selection.Find
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then
                Debug.Print i & " " & Selection.Text
                i = i + 1
            ' Move to the next character
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
        Else
            Debug.Print "Done"
            blnFound = False
        End If
    End With
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working.  Now I unfortunately I have a new issue - I have a Table of Contents in my document and your solution is picking up heading in that and the document.  Do you know of a way to prevent this?  Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if the title of your table of contents is also using the Heading 1 style? If so, I suggest using (or creating) a different style for that heading so it doesn't get picked up by the macro. (Note, I added one more line to the code just now.)